# Поиск короткого пути в области точке

Tags: алгоритм, графы, 3d, 2d, поиск-пути

Дано произвольное 2D или 3D облако точек. 
Необходимо найти кратчайшее растояние от произвольной точки A 
в точку B.

[image]

Есть ли оптимальные алгоритмы под данные условия?

Теоретически, я бы использовал либо QuadTree/OctaTree или же KD-Tree для поиска n-соседей скажем точки A и находил бы самого близкого (N1) к B, искал бы соседе N1 и т.д, пока в соседях не оказалась бы точка B.

Но возможно есть более элегантные решения?

Comment: Не знаю насколько подходит, но есть алгоритм [A*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*)

Comment: Я бы использовал цикл по всем точкам и сравнивал бы расстояния от начальной и до конечной

Comment: Не люблю A*, он зависит от эвристической оценки расстояния, из-за которой может наврать. Видел довольно простые на вид случаи, когда алгоритм ошибался и **кратчайшего** пути не давал. В принципе, стандартные алгоритмы на графах должны подойти. Провести рёбра для соседей, между которыми можно ходить, стоимостью ребра будет расстояние по Евклиду между соединёнными соседями. И с Дейкстрой в добрый путь :) тут велосипед не нужен

Answer (score 0):

Вы что-то недоговариваете. Наикратчайшее расстояние от А до Б - прямая. И не важно что там за другие точки есть.

Если же у вас есть некий граф точек - то A* это то что вам нужно. Вопрос лишь в выборе эвристики оценки расстояния - если у вас евклидово пространство - то тут все просто (берете расстояние). Иначе - никакая эвристика не поможет и потребуется полный перебор (Дейкстра?).

Comment: Безусловно я имел ввиду путь через другие точки.
Проблему решил за счет построения графа.